# Добавление класса по клику внутри обработчика addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Необходимо добавить класс при клике на элемент.
Вроде всё правильно пишу, но код не работает:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
cells.addEventListener('click', selectDate);
function selectDate() {
    cells.className = ' active';
}
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwxuf5ea/15/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*className*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/className) - это уже готовая строка: когда вы ей присваиваете значение, она полностью теряет старое.

Вместо этого свойства можно использовать [*classList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
element.classList.add(class);
```

Но у вас есть ещё одна проблема:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Данный метод возвращает коллекцию, а приведенные методы, включая и [*addEventListener*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), работают с конкретным элементом.

Для решения вам нужно в цикле обойти элементы и каждому добавить обработчик, например, так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', selectDate);
}
```

И немного поменять сам обработчик:

```
function selectDate() {
    this.classList.add('active');// this в данном случае будет указывать на кликнутый элемент.
}
```

Либо оставить вариант с *className*:

```
function selectDate() {
    this.className += ' active';// this в данном случае будет указывать на кликнутый элемент.
}
```

**Обратите внимание:** используется оператор **+=**, который равносилен

```
this.className = this.className + ' active':
```

Comment: мне и надо к готовой строке добавить класс. перед классом поставила пробел чтобы класс не заменился, а добавился

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, я как раз и написал, почему ваш метод не работает.

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно! теперь буду удалять класс по клику)

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, пройдите по ссылкам указанным в ответе - там описано как эти функции и свойства работают