# Проверить наличие CSS класса в javascript

Tags: javascript

Как проверить наличие или отсутствие класса у элемента на **чистом javascript**?

Необходимо добавить класс элементу по клику, но при этом проверить наличие у него этого класса перед добавлением, чтобы класс не дублировался.

вот код:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for(var i=0; i<cells.length;i++){
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', selectDate);    
}
function selectDate(){
    this.className += ' active';
}
```

ссылка на полный код [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/fwxuf5ea/18/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сделала так - по клику добавляется класс и удаляется при повторном клике. вот код:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<cells.length;i++){
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', selectDate);
}

function selectDate(){
    if(this.classList.contains('active')){
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }else {
        this.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

ссылка на полный код: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/fwxuf5ea/25/)

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы городить такой if, раз уж Вы используете `classList`, можно воспользоваться готовой функцией: `classList.toggle('active')`. И совет, ставить обработчики в цикле не хорошо, лучше повесить его на родителя, так шустрее будет работать.

Comment: спасибо, сработало)

Comment: Вместо того, что у Вас в `selectDate(){}` надо написать проcто `this.classList.toggle('active')`

Comment: да, я уже применила http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/fwxuf5ea/29/

Comment: и еще, для понимания, могу я использовать функцию toggle если не подключена jquery? у меня все работает, но если браузер будет старый?

Comment: Да, объект `DOMTokenList`, который возвращается через вызов `classList` у любого домовского элемента, нативен, ему ничего кроме браузера не нужно. [`classList`](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) работает с 10IE, вполне неплохо. Для поддержки в старых браузерах нужен [полифилл](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), он реализует `classList` через регулярки, это то, как вам ответил tutankhamun.

Answer (score 18):

Вам поможет метод [`classList.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) вместо *className*

> **contains** ( String )
>      Проверяет, есть ли данный класс у элемента (вернет true или false)

использовать можно так:

```
if(this.classList.contains('active'))
```

где *this* должен быть html-элементом.

Comment: Отличная штука. Не знал. Спасибо

Comment: @tutankhamun, они постепенно расширяют интерфейсы дом элементов :-)

Comment: Так скоро jQuery не понадобится в 95% случаев, в который он сейчас почти необходим :)

Comment: @tutankhamun, а в каких например он сейчас почти необходим?

Comment: Я вот уже и не уверен, что знаю ответ на ваш вопрос :) Внедрение `document.querySelector()` и `document.querySelectorAll()` очень сильно подорвало фундамент _jQuery_. Получается что в сухом остатке только поддержка старых браузеров

Comment: @tutankhamun, ага, ну может быть еще какие-нибудь мобильные браузеры

Comment: как эту проверку прописать? пока не получается реализовать...

вот код:



var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<cells.length;i++){
    var findClass = cells.classList.contains('active');
    if(i !== findClass) {
        cells[i].addEventListener('click', selectDate);
    }
}
function selectDate(){
    this.className += ' active';
}

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, добавил пример использования.

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, данная функция возвращает _true_ или _false_, а вы ее с числом сравниваете

Comment: пишу так: var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<cells.length;i++){
    if(cells.classList.contains('active')) {
        cells[i].addEventListener('click', selectDate);
    }
}

выдает ошибку "Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined"

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, вы опять совершаете ту же ошибку, что и в [предыдущем вашем вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471258/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-addeventlistener)

Comment: тогда как мне проверить наличие класса, и если его нет, то добавить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32665/discussion-between-grundy-and-marina-voronova).

Comment: @voronovam, Вам не надо делать проверку перед добавлением. `classList.add` не дублирует класс, если он уже есть.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, подозреваю, автор уже разобрался за 4 года :)

Comment: @Grundy, тьфу ты. Как обычно не смотрю на даты хД Кто поднял вопрос 4-летней давности? ХД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, там ответ дали новый :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться следующей функцией:

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
    var rx = new RegExp('(?:^| )' + className + '(?: |$)');
    return rx.test(element.className);
}
```

Плюс такого решения - работает даже на древних браузерах

Comment: пока сложновато для меня... это чистый js?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, чище некуда :-)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно проверить именно наличия класса то используйте такую конструкцию

```
!!~elem.getAttribute("class").indexOf("my__class")
```

Метод:

```
classList.toggle('active')
```

добавляет класс при его отсутствие и удаляет при его наличии.

Метод:

```
parent.contains(child)
```

Возвращает true, если parent содержит child или parent == child
То есть если у нас несколько child то придется проверять в цикле. Да и опять же вложенность

Comment: _!!~elem.getAttribute("class").indexOf("my__class")_ - плохой вариант, например зацепит `my__class1`, ну и читаемость ужасная лучше обычный if, чем !!~

Comment: 1. js насколько я знаю все задачи делаются для определенной цели. Если конечно у человека будут в одном элементе содержать классы active + no-active + active-elem. То да. Нужно делать через регулярки. 2. Вы вообще знаете для чего конструкция предназначена !!~ ?  При чем тут  "лучше обычный if, чем !!~" ???

Comment: При том, что намного проще читается обычное сравнение с -1 чем куча спец символов идущих друг за другом :-) собственно и такой конструкции !!~ в языке нет, это ж просто куча унарных операторов и для большей экспрессии можно и 10 восклицательных знаков поставить :)

Comment: по вашему конструкция if( -1 ==  elem.getAttribute("class").indexOf("my__class")) читается лучше чем if(~elem.getAttribute("class").indexOf("my__class")) ?

Comment: Не, такая тоже плохо читается :-) в нормальном порядке надо писать :-)

Comment: Да?) Кто то говорит наоборот что нужен такой порядок. Не (a == true) а наоборот (true == a). Ну а раз на то пошло то if((" " + elem.getAttribute("class") + 
 " ").indexOf("my__class") > -1)

Comment: про обратный порядок говорят те, кто не следит сколько знаков равно ставит.  Смысл обрамлять значения атрибута class в пробелы - нет, они не влияют на работу indexOf в данном случае, и как проходила проверка с `my__class1` так и продолжит проходить

Comment: странно. последний код я вообще из jQuery взял метод hasClass. вы уверены в том что говорите? про обратный порядок самому не удобно переучиваться но люди требуют

Comment: Ага, уверен :-) ты неправильно "взял" из jQuery :)

Comment: Кстате да. Спасибо. С этим согласен