# Проверить наличие класса у дочернего элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно проверить наличие класса у дочернего элемента и, в зависимости от наличия, присваивать необходимые стили. Вот код, который смог сам написать. Может кто знает что нужно поправить?

```
if(!$('.rev_block').children('video_btn2').hasClass{
    $('.photo_btn').css('top', '215');
    }else{
      $('.photo_btn').css('top', '165');
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471853/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-css-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
if($('.rev_block .video_btn2').hasClass('CLASS_NAME')){
    $('.photo_btn').css('top', '215');
} else {
    $('.photo_btn').css('top', '165');
}
```

Вместо `CLASS_NAME` вставить нужный вам класс (без точки, так как функция принимает строку)